# Created Two DNS in two different Provider

Tags: azure, dns, hosting

I am new in developed website. I have accidentally created a new DNS zone in Microsoft Azure which the domain already has its own DNS in another hosting company. The hosting company help to handle email of the domain.
Besides that, the company was also pointed the root domain to my web app by using A record. 
The website now can be accessed via domain.com but not www.domain.com.
What is the solution for me to point www.domain.com to my web app domain.azurewebsites.net and without affect mail.domain.com?

Comment: Add a new CNAME/A record in the other hosting company? Otherwise, if you intend to use Azure DNS, you would need to add all the other records that are currently in the other hosting company's nameservers. and then switch to use Azure DNS nameservers.

Comment: If I deleted the Azure DNS and add cname with www to the other hosting company, will it affect the mail.domain.com?

Comment: Is the Azure DNS even used at the moment? In order to use it, you would have to specify it as the authoritative nameserver(s). Any way, it will not affect the other subdomain. All of the stuff is registered in the other hosting provider right? Adding a new subdomain record there cannot affect other records. Queries for mail.domain.com will still get the same result as before.

Comment: The Azure DNS is not using at the moment.

Comment: @juunas how about if I set cname * and point to domain.azurewebsites.net, will it affect mail.domain.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the solution for me to point www.domain.com to my web app
>   domain.azurewebsites.net and without affect mail.domain.com?

We can add **CNAME record** to your web app service like this:

```
Host          type                value
www           CNAME               xxx.domain.azurewebsites.net
```

> how about if I set cname * and point to domain.azurewebsites.net, will
>   it affect mail.domain.com?

If you set CNAME * and point to domain.azurewebsites.net, that will not affect `mail.domain.com`.

Because mail type is **MX record**, that will **not affect** CNAME record.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using web app services instead of cloud app service.

Comment: @user8764920 ok, that work for app service too. we can set CNAME record to Azure web app service. I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: @user8764920 Does that work for you? please let me know if you need more help:)